# Lanczos-Lovelock gravity Lagrangian

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, curvature, quantum-gravity

I am studying the Lanczos-Lovelock theory of gravity where the Lagrangian density is

$$ \mathcal{L} = \sqrt{-g} \sum_{i=0}^{t} \alpha_{i} \mathcal{R}^i $$

With $ \alpha $ being the coupling constants and

$$ \mathcal{R}^n = \frac{1}{2^n} \delta^{\mu_{1}\nu_{1} ... \mu_{n}\nu_{n}}_{\alpha_1 \beta_1 ... \alpha_n \beta_n} \prod_{k=1}^n R^{\mu_k \nu_k}_{\alpha_k \beta_k}$$

I was wondering

1 how would we expand the sum? does the $ i $ index run over spacetime dimensions or is it an abstract index?

2 does the $ \mathcal{R}^n $ have any physical interpretation?

3 how would we reach this Lagrangian solely from general relativity?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovelock_theory_of_gravity): “Each term $\mathcal{R}^n$ in $\mathcal{L}$ corresponds to the dimensional extension of the Euler density in $2n$ dimensions, so that these only contribute to the equations of motion for $n < D/2$. Consequently, without lack of generality, $t$ in the equation above can be taken to be $D = 2t + 2$ for even dimensions and $D = 2t + 1$ for odd dimensions.”

Comment: *How would we reach this Lagrangian solely from general relativity?* This is a *generalization* of the Lagrangian density for GR, so it doesn’t follow “solely” from GR.

Comment: I recommend that you work out the first three terms for $i=0,1,2$ and compare them with Wikipedia.

Comment: I tried to do this but i end up with a $ \frac{1}{16\pi G} $ factor multiplying the R scalar in the $ i = 1 $ term. Which gives the Lagrangian $ \mathcal{L} = \left( 2\Lambda + \frac{1}{16\pi} R \right) \sqrt{-g} $ instead of the usual Einstein-Hilbert lagrangian $ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{16\pi G}\left( 2\Lambda + R \right)$